# Many-to-Many Checkbox fields that work in both MySQL and MS Access

Tags: mysql, ms-access, checkbox, many-to-many, normalization

I've been tasked with creating a MySQL database which will be connected to by MS Access via ODBC.  The MySQL database will store values which will utilize around 10 checkbox fields.  I'm having trouble visualizing how MS Access will let me interact with these fields efficiently.

The data must be able to be edited via the Access front end form, as well as via a web-interface (not too worried about the web-interface portion).

Here are some examples of fields that I'm having trouble with:

```
> bloom_month (Checkboxes to select 1-many months of the year)
> bloom_color (Checkboxes to select 0-many colors from a separate table)
```

The way that I'd deal with this if I were only doing the web-app would be to use a linking-table (aka: associate table) to create a basic many-to-many relationship.  Is this also the best way to handle the static "bloom_month" field as the months will never change (ie I'd be setting up a table that just has id - month pairs)?

That said, I could be way off in my thinking as it seems Access would prefer a flat-table structure with a 0/-1 tinyint field for each possible checkbox.  This method just seems wrong to me, and it also wouldn't allow dynamically adding/removing colors from a separate table (ie if a bloom_color was removed/added the table structure would have to change).

Additionally, any help, or pointers on how to work with MS Access Many-To-Many relationships utilizing checkboxes as selectors while storing the data in MySQL would be much appreciated.  I can't seem to find much on the subject, although my google-fu is admittedly weak.

Comment: stick with good normalization practices.  then work through the UI

Answer (score 0):

Once you make the ODBC connection in Access you can use the MySQL table the same as any table made in Access. Then you can build an Access query which will resolve your many to many relationship into something like the flat-file format that Access seems to like. In Access queries are presented to the user as persistent objects, so you can then make forms based off of those queries.

Comment: Awesome.  This is the answer I was looking for. Many thanks for your assistance.  I think I can make this work now.  I hadn't thought of using Access queries to simulate the flat-table structure.

Comment: If this is the answer you needed, please check the green arrow next to it (this helps build both of our reps).